# How to dynamically run python code in C, which has access to the C functions

Tags: python, c, shared-libraries, cython

I have a `shared library` and every symbol is resolved by it, then I have a `main.c` where I'm able to call library functions.
This is how I compiled `main.c`

```
gcc -rdynamic main.c -o main library.so -ldl
```

Now in my main I want to be able to dynamically run some `python` code, which needs to be able to call library functions. Maybe `Cython` helps me doing this.

So, that's what I need:

1. `library.so` linked to the `main` program
2. `main.c` which initialize `python` and dynamically load `script.pyx`
3. `script.pyx` which is able to call `C` functions defined in `library.so`

In that way I can use `python` to do some stuffs on my `C` application using also library functions, is this possible?

Comment: You want to write a python script to run it inside a C program using functions that are already linked and usable by the C program in the first place? That seems like one or two steps more than needed. It's definitely possible, but needlessly complicated. What's the real problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I want. I simplified my problem to explain it better, but I have to modify a big application which takes a lot of time to build, so I'm asking if I can do it using a language which has not to be compiled.

Comment: Do you *necessarily* need to use the Python C API and its internal functions to execute a python script from within C or would you also be ok with a simple `system("python myscript.py")` (still calling C functions from `script.py`)? The latter would be quite trivial, I don't know much about the other option.

Comment: I need to use the Python C API.

Comment: Got it, just making sure.

Comment: You could use cython to do this, you'd need to wrap your C API in cython and then just call the wrapped functions from Python. See https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/external_C_code.html

Comment: You can load shared libraries into python using `ctypes` which is a builtin module. Neither cython not C extension API is needed